# Apple signin authorization returned an error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)

Tags: apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I am integrating Apple sing-in feature into my app. It was working fine before but suddenly it shows this error and don't return any information like username, email etc. Capabilities are are also turned on. Please help me finding solution for it.

Answer (score 4):

Are you testing this on a Simulator? Seems to be a common problem on simulators.

Comment: i have same problem on simulator ? is there a fix for it ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I don't use the Simulator anymore exactly for these little reasons...I find it easier to just test directly on device.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your app using from App using Apple ID

1. Setting
2. Click on your apple id (Showing in setting screen)
3. Password & Security
4. Apps using Apple ID
5. your app (swipe to delete)

Remove from the list and try to fresh install it will work